# Can PHP exec() return nested arrays?

Tags: php, unix, terminal, command-line-interface

I am using PHP exec() to run a script that outputs a 3 column, 5 row data table. Right now each row is a single value in my array as follows:

```
1 => "Nancy  Female   32   05/10/2012"
2 => "Drew   Male     32   06/16/2012"
3 => "Websy  Female   32   11/05/2012"
4 => "Namez  Male     32   09/20/2012"
```

Can I get it to return a nested array for the values in each row?

```
1 => 
    1 => Nancy
    2 => Female
    3 => 32
    4 => 05/10/2012
2 => 
    1 => Drew
    2 => Male
    3 => 32
    4 => 06/16/2012
```

I can always use a delimiter, and rearrange the array afterwards, but didn't if know there some funcationality to exec() that can do this.

Comment: Say what??????? (question marks are only added to fill the comment minimum char length, lets just assume there were only three)

Comment: I assume you're talking about the `&output` parameter to [`exec`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), since that will give you an array where each line from the output is a separate entry (the return value of `exec` is only the last line). But the answer is **no**, as Amber explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All [`exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) knows about is *lines* of output; it has no further knowledge of what is in those lines.